# Modify Active Directory group membership with powershell if title of user account changes

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am attempting to use PowerShell to remove users from a security group if their user account "title" changes.

- Group name = Development Team
- User Title = Developer

I want to get all members of the `Development Team` security group and if the members of this group have a title other than `Developer`, remove the user from the group.

This is just an example and would be used for role based group maintenance based on title. If a user's title changes, their group membership would change via this scheduled script.

This script removes all members of the group instead of just the members where the user's title does not equal `Developer`. How can I modify the script to only remove users with a title not equal to `Developer`?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$groupname = 'Development Team'
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname

foreach($member in $members)
{
   if($member.title -notlike 'Developer')
   {
      Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname -Member $member.samaccountname
   }
}
```

---

Based on the info from [LisaJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10076590/lisaj) below, this is what the new script looks like.  Works!

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$groupname = 'Development Team'
$members = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(!(title=Developer))(memberOf=cn=Development Team,ou=Security Groups,dc=domain,dc=com))"

foreach($member in $members)
{
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname -Member $member.samaccountname
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title is not an attribute returned with get-adgroupmember, so all $member.title values are not "Developer" because the value is always null. I would use an LDAP filter like

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(!(title=Developer))(memberOf=cn=Development Group,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com))"
```

To identify accounts which need to be removed from the group. This filter returns a set of users that *are* members of the Development Group group (you'll need the proper fully qualified DN for the group) but whose title is not "Developer". Use your foreach on *those* to remove-adgroupmember.

You can also provision users into the group when their title becomes developer using

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(title=Developer)(!(memberOf=cn=Development Group,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com)))"
```

To identify all accounts that are *not* a member of "Development Group" and have "Developer" as their title.